# HTML5 validation on quantity in woocommerce, change error message

Tags: html, wordpress, validation, woocommerce

I am creating my first online shop.

**Problem:** I want to show, error message for quantity validation.
Stock quantity is not showing in product detail page but it is showing in cart page. I have share both pages screenshot below.

Product Detail: http://prntscr.com/93ajnj

Cart: http://prntscr.com/93ajuk

I have use below code in woocommerce > single-product > add-to-cart > variable.php

```
<div class="quantity"><strong>Quantity </strong>
   <input type="number" step="<?php echo esc_attr( $step ); ?>" <?php if ( is_numeric( $min_value ) ) : ?>min="<?php echo esc_attr( $min_value ); ?>"<?php endif; ?> <?php if ( is_numeric( $max_value ) ) : ?>max="<?php echo esc_attr( $max_value ); ?>"<?php endif; ?> name="<?php echo esc_attr( $input_name ); ?>" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $input_value ); ?>" class="input-text qty text" size="4" oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Sorry! we have only <?php echo esc_attr( $max_value ); ?> shirts in your selected size.')"
onchange="try{setCustomValidity('')}catch(e){}" />
</div>
```

Any help in this regards will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.
P.S. [link](http://www.calabria.com.pk/products/) of website.

Comment: Just stock up more shirts

Comment: I am confuse that is it showing in cart page but not in product detail page. http://prntscr.com/93ajuk